# ehcache - permanent caching

Tags: java, ehcache, mybatis

I am beginner to Ehcache.

I am trying to do cache SQL query result via mybatis xml and ehcache is caching the query with its result, but it clears the cached data once the operation gets completed even the same JVM instance is running.

Can anyone advise how to store the cache either in disk/memory till JVM termiates?

Code snippet of `mybatis-mapper.xml`

```xml
<cache type="org.mybatis.caches.ehcache.EhcacheCache">
    <property name="eternal" value="false" />
    <property name="maxElementsInMemory" value="100000" />
    <property name="timeToIdleSeconds" value="3600" />
    <property name="timeToLiveSeconds" value="3600" />
    <property name="memoryStoreEvictionPolicy" value="LFU" />
    <property name="statistics" value="true" />
</cache>
```

.....

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [Ehcache Persistence](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/fast-restart.html)

Comment: understanding the Ehcache persistence.  Is it possible to use <persistence strategy="...." /> inside the mybatis mapper xml instead of creating separate ehcache config file.

'<cache type="org.mybatis.caches.ehcache.EhcacheCache">
  <property name="eternal" value="true" />
  <property name="maxElementsInMemory" value="100000"/>
  <property name="memoryStoreEvictionPolicy" value="LRU" />
  <property name="flushInterval" value="60000" />
  <property name="statistics" value="true" />
  <persistence strategy=”none”/> --> not working
 </cache> '

Answer (score 0):

Not a specialist of the MyBatis - Ehcache bridge. But from your configuration sample, assuming you never want expiry, do the following changes:

- `eternal` property to be set to `true`
- Remove the two `timeToXXX` properties

This will make sure expiry never gets triggered. Note though that a cache can still evict to control resource consumption.

Comment: Tried with the eternal as "true" with no TTL,TTI settings. But still the same. Just done the debugging of ehcache and noticed clear() method in TransactionalCache is being invoked by default once commit is done and due to that cache is getting cleared.  Is there any properties to skip this clear() method?  Correct me if understanding is wrong.

'  @Override
  public void clear() {
    reset();
    clearOnCommit = true;
  }'

Answer (score 0):

In order to fixing this issue, we need to explicitly mention the below attributes in the your mapper.xml
1) useCache="true" and  flushCache="false" for select operation
2) flushCache="false" for all your insert/update/delete operation

Sample code snippets:-

```
<select id="getTestData" parameterType="map" resultMap="testDtls"  useCache="true" flushCache="false" >

<insert id="insertTestData" parameterType="map" flushCache="false" >
```